# Why stdout for error messages

Tags: c, stdout, stderr, error-reporting

Is there any reason to print errors on stdout and not on stderr?

I see some People use stdout, respectively printf(), to print error message. Is there any reason to do this or are there only to lazy to use stderr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's lazyness. stderr was created to print error messages, so you can redirect the output of a program without having mixed error messages. Also, I think stderr is unbuffered by default, so if your program crash, all the error messages up to the point where it crashed are printed (this behaviour can be modified by the use of setvbuf).

Comment: Thank you. "so you can redirect the output of a program without having mixed error messages" i know this, exactly this is my problem, respectively that i can not.